# Received below error while starting docker container " Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348"

Tags: docker, containers

I am using

```
$ sudo docker start <Container Id>
```

Below error I received

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"-f\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
Error: failed to start containers: 885dccbc45d1
```

Comment: What is your system distro version and Docker version?

Comment: I am using EC2 instance ubuntu M/C .  Version:       18.03.0-ce                                                                                     
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-21:~$ sudo docker version
Client:
 Version:       18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24
 Built: Wed Mar 21 23:10:22 2018
 OS/Arch:       linux/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Comment: Any news on this issue ? Had the exact same error while trying to run a [Node.js container](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/README.md#how-to-use-this-image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by deleting the most recent docker image - it would seem that a failure in the previous image is being persisted into the next build.

Run `docker images` to see a list of docker images on your machine. Then run `docker rmi -f <most_recent_image_ID>` and try building again.